# Mule DataMapper Map to Map(Many to single) mapping

Tags: mule

I want to get map output from using input of 2 maps.

One input map has following data:
`[xyz:1234,abc:name]`

Second input map has following data:
`[xyza:jack,abcd:denial]`

Now, the output map should be like this:
`[xyz:jack,abc:denial]`

Is it possible using datamapper where i can give two maps as input and get output map?
If it is then how?

Comment: Hi @Lovish, rules for merging the two maps are not clear, can you add more detail?

Comment: Sure, following are the rules:
if(map1.key=="xyz" and map2.key=="xyza"){map3.key="xyz"; map3.value="jack"};
Key of first map will key of output map
and Value of second map will value of output map